# Sonar eclipse plugin needs sonar server installed

Tags: sonarqube

Is Sonar eclipse plugin needs a valid sonar server installed locally or remotely to do the quality profiles in eclipse.

Thanks,
cabear

Comment: I would suggest you to use sonar-lint plugin. Sonar-lint doesn't​ require any sonar instance, comes with standard set of rules this is good for IDE performance as opposed to sonarqube plugins for Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As per the ["Configuring SonarQube in Eclipse"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) documentation page, you can see that this is indeed required to have a SonarQube server installed somewhere.

> If your project is not already under analysis, you'll need to declare
>   it through the SonarQube web interface.
>
> Once your project exists in SonarQube, you're ready to get started
>   with SonarQube in Eclipse.